# Non interactive Zero Knowledge Proof for Satisfiability of Pairing Product Equations

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, implementation

[In the paper](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/J.Groth/NIZKGroupSignFull.pdf) "Simulation-Sound NIZK Proofs for a Practical Language and
Constant Size Group Signatures" from Groth, the section 6 describes a NIZK proof for pairing product equations.

I only know the basics in the domain of zero knowledge proofs and I saw some basic algorithm. What I would like to know is if there is a way to implement the prover and verifier algorithm ? By using some already existing implmentation like the Schnorr one or another one that I could adapt ?

In summary, I would like to know if there are ways to implement the algorithms shown in the paper. Or is it just a theoretical state at the moment?

Comment: It is definitely implementable. It only uses conventional primitives.

Comment: libsnark on github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read some part of above paper, definitely you can find implementations of such prover and verifier algorithms, even more complicated ones. For example, you can find implementations of prover and verifier in several zero-knowledge proofs in [Libsnrak](https://github.com/scipr-lab/libsnark) library.

By the way, you can also find implementation of [Groth-Maller](https://github.com/scipr-lab/libsnark/tree/master/libsnark/zk_proof_systems/ppzksnark/r1cs_se_ppzksnark) simulation-extractable zk-SNARK from Crypto 2017 in Libsnark that considers quite similar concept to the paper that you have mentioned.

I would also recommend to look at implementation of [Pinocchio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/pinocchio-nearly-practical-verifiable-computation/), a practical verifiable computation system, that has implementation of a prover and a verifier in a zero-knowledge SNARK that are particular type of none-interactive zero-knowledge proofs.